# Замена произвольного текста на теги html (в AnkiDroid)

Tags: android, html

Добрый день!

Есть проблема с добавлением скрытого текста на карточки AnkiDroid через телефон. По сути нужно добавить лишь теги  в коде карточки, мне уже помогли с этим. Но на телефоне не нашёл угловых скобок и вообще это неудобно. Есть ли способ написать в коде карточки `.span.` для замены на `<span>` и `./span.` для замены на `</span>`, чтобы замена производилась перед запуском кода на html? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Угловые скобки появляются, если перейти в режим символьно-цифровой клавиатуры, а затем нажать на дополнительную кнопку (на картинке - первая во втором ряду):

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Вооружившись этим знанием, идём в настройки клавиатуры Gboard -> Словарь -> Личный словарь -> английский -> добавляем слово и ставим на него "быстрые клавиши".

   Например: в строчку слова вводите `<span>`, а в строчку `Быстрые клавиши` вводите `sspan`, сохраняете, теперь у вас при вводе сочетания символов "sspan" клавиатура будет предлагать подставить вместо этого `<span>`.